# Access related entities in model definition

Tags: python, django, model

I got this model definition in Django 1.8:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
            return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.number)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __str__(self):
            return "(%s) %s" % (self.number, self.name)
```

How can i access the category name in the Item model?

When i try this, I got an error saying, that there is no attribute 'category':

```
def __str__(self):
    return "(%s) %s - %s" % (self.number, self.name, self.category.name)
```

Comment: `self.category_id.name`, maybe? You named it that.

Comment: ... which you shouldn't have done. `category` is the proper name for the Django field.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to django.  category_id is working fine. I will rename it to category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need to define a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field with a `_id` at the end as Django itself does that internally.**

As per Django 1.8 docs on [ForeignKey database representation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#database-representation):

> Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create
>   its database column name.

You can instead do something like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) # remove '_id' at the end 

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s) %s - %s" % (self.number, self.name, self.category.name)
```